undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'
I get this error when I try to update applications in the admin panel
my controller
frozen_string_literal: true
class Admin::OrdersController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    paginated_orders
  end

  def show
    order
  end

  def update
    result = Cmd::Order::Update.call(order: order, current_user: current_user, params: order_params)
    if result.success?
      redirect_to admin_order_path(order)
    else
      render json: { validate: true, data: errors_data(result.order.order) }, status: 422
    end
  end

  private

  def paginated_orders
    @paginated_orders ||= orders.page(params[:page])
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.find(params[:id]).decorate
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order)
      .permit(:position_search, :specialization_id, :department, :employment, :work_address, :medical_examination,
              :transport, :workwear, :housing, :food_nutrition, :security_check, :training, :trial_period,
              :position_id, :state, :number_of_employees, :qualification, :experience, :employment_type, :work_schedule, :city_id,
              :salary_from, :salary_to, :salary_condition, :about_job, :company_offers, :requirements, :recruiter_name,
              :recruiter_position, :recruiter_phone, :recruiter_communication_method, :recruiter_email, :customer_price,
              :contractor_price, :warranty_period, :admin_update, other_info: {})
  end

  def orders
    @orders ||= Order.moderation
  end
end

my Cmd::Order::Update
def call
        order.assign_attributes(order_params)
        context.fail!(full_messages: order.errors.messages) unless order.save

        Cmd::UserActionLogger::Log.call(params: logger_params)
      end

      private

      def order_params
        permitted_keys = %i[department position_id salary_from salary_to salary salary_condition specialization_id city_id work_address
                            experience employment_type work_schedule qualification employment about_job
                            company_offers requirements category medical_examination transport workwear
                            food_nutrition housing security_check training trial_period recruiter_name
                            recruiter_position recruiter_phone recruiter_communication_method
                            recruiter_email skill_list other_info]

        order_params = params[:order].slice(*permitted_keys)
        # TODO: remake position_id to synonym_id in format
        position_id = order_params[:position_id]
        position = find_position(position_id)
        order_params.merge!(position_id: position&.id, synonym_id: position_id)
      end

Tried to avoid nill this way
order_params = params[:order]&.slice(*permitted_keys) || {}

but then the page refreshes and gives an SMS that the record does not exist or was not found, although there is a record in the database

Please add the stack trace to the question/

Params are sent to the call method, but don't seem to be captured on the other end.  Where does order come from in the call method?

Unfortunately the question as it stands does not make sense. You are calling Cmd::Order::Update::call with arguments but the call method posted (which appears to be an instance method rather than a class instance method) does not accept arguments, this would raise an error of it's own. This method also returns the result of a call to Cmd::UserActionLogger::Log::call so your result object would be predicated on the success of logging? Please clarify the question.
